# How can I prove discontinuity of $f(x)$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$f$ : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=x$ $\quad$ If $x \leqq 1$

$f(x)=x+2$ $\quad$ If $x>1$

If I draw the graph, I can realize $f(x)$ is not continuous.

But I want to prove this discontinuity by showing that an open set $O$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1} (O)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ exists.

How should I decide $O$ ?

Comment: What open sets have you tried?
Remember, if you don't post your efforts about the problem, it looks like you are trying others to make your homework for you.

Comment: $(1/2, 2)$ should do the job, since $f^{-1}((1/2, 2)) = (1/2, 1]$ which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Well, you know there is a discontinuity at $x = 1$ where the value of $f(x)$ jumps from 1 to 3.  Maybe that gives a clue as to what point might be in the open set you need to to use.

Comment: @jjagmath I let $(0,1)$ or $(3,5)$ be $O$ but these didn't work. I was not able to pay attention to the point of graph between $1$ and $3$, where $f(x)$ jumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O = (0, 2)$. Then, $f^{-1}[O] = (0, 1]$, which is not open. The strategy is that when you want to show the discontinuity by inverse image, let your open interval include the function value at the discontinuous point. In the example, we see that $f(1) = 1 \in O$.